# pre_get_posts causes Custom Posts appear under 'Pages' menu

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, pre-get-posts

In order to enable pagination on for custom post archive I've added pre_get_posts function. But, funnily it caused my custom posts be duplicated under 'Pages' menu.

Here is the code that causes the problem. Please, advise.

```
   function truck_pre_pagination( $qry ) {
        if ( $qry->is_main_query() ) {
            $qry->set('orderby','date');
            $qry->set('order','ASC');
            $qry->set('posts_per_page',12);
            $qry->set('post_type','trucks');
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts','truck_pre_pagination');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$qry->is_main_query()` will be true on every main query on your site, front end and admin. You need to add another more specific condition to target only the page you're trying to modify the query on, like [`is_post_type_archive('trucks')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive).